# Obfuscated scientific calculator. Please explain how it works

Tags: c, obfuscation

I was trying to understand how does the following program work.  It is a command-line scientific calculator.  The source is taken from [here](http://ioccc.org/2011/hou/hou.c).  It seemed pretty readable for an IOCCC entry but apparently it's not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define clear 1;if(c>=11){c=0;sscanf(_,"%lf%c",&r,&c);while(*++_-c);}\
  else if(argc>=4&&!main(4-(*_++=='('),argv))_++;g:c+=
#define puts(d,e) return 0;}{double a;int b;char c=(argc<4?d)&15;\
  b=(*_%__LINE__+7)%9*(3*e>>c&1);c+=
#define I(d) (r);if(argc<4&&*#d==*_){a=r;r=usage?r*a:r+a;goto g;}c=c
#define return if(argc==2)printf("%f\n",r);return argc>=4+
#define usage main(4-__LINE__/26,argv)
#define calculator *_*(int)
#define l (r);r=--b?r:
#define _ argv[1]
#define x

double r;
int main(int argc,char** argv){
  if(argc<2){
    puts(
      usage: calculator 11/26+222/31
      +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~calculator-\
      !                          7.584,367 )
      +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+
      ! clear ! 0 ||l   -x  l   tan  I (/) |
      +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+
      ! 1 | 2 | 3 ||l  1/x  l   cos  I (*) |
      +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+
      ! 4 | 5 | 6 ||l  exp  l  sqrt  I (+) |
      +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+
      ! 7 | 8 | 9 ||l  sin  l   log  I (-) |
      +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(0
    );
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It compiles without warnings on gcc 4.7.2 (Linux) with `-Wall`.  I attempted to simplify it but any further changes to the slightly modified form given below start to produce unexpected results (incorrect output).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define clear 1;if(c>=11){c=0;sscanf(_,"%lf%c",&r,&c);while(*++_-c);}\
  else if(argc>=4&&!main(4-(*_++=='('),argv))_++;g:c+=
#define puts(d,e) return 0;}{double a;int b;char c=(argc<4?d)&15;\
  b=(*_%__LINE__+7)%9*(3*e>>c&1);c+=
#define I(d) (r);if(argc<4&&*#d==*_){a=r;r=usage?r*a:r+a;goto g;}c=c
#define return if(argc==2)printf("%f\n",r);return argc>=4+
#define usage main(4-__LINE__/26,argv)
#define calculator *_*(int)
#define l (r);r=--b?r:
#define _ argv[1]
#define x

double r;
int main(int argc,char** argv){
  if(argc<2){
    puts(
      usage: calculator 11/26+222/31
      +calculator-\
      !                          7.584,367 )
      +
      ! clear ! 0 ||l   -x  l   tan  I (/) |
      +
      ! 1 | 2 | 3 ||l  1/x  l   cos  I (*) |
      +
      ! 4 | 5 | 6 ||l  exp  l  sqrt  I (+) |
      +
      ! 7 | 8 | 9 ||l  sin  l   log  I (-) |
      +(0);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Can somebody please explain how it works?

Comment: Study the preprocessed form of this source code, perhaps with `gcc -C -E obfusc.c | grep -v '^#' | indent > obfusc.i`  then look inside ̀`obfusc.i`

Comment: Certainly not. IOCCC entries take me at least two hours to analyse (I would entirely refactor the code in the course of trying to understand what it does), and the long explanation would probably take a day to write, and be completely out of scope for this site IMHO.

Comment: Note the `__LINE__` macro, which makes it sensitive to line breaks. It is used to identify the `/*+-` operators.

Answer (score 4):

It expands to look like this:

```
double r;
int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc < 2)
    {
      if (argc == 2)
    printf ("%f\n", r);
      return argc >= 4 + 0;
    }
  {
    double a;
    int b;
    char c = (argc < 4 ? main (4 - 21 / 26,
                   argv) : *argv[1] * (int) 11 / 26 + 222 / 31 +
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*argv[1] * (int) -!7.584) & 15;
    b = (*argv[1] % 21 + 7) % 9 * (3 * 367 >> c & 1);
    c += +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+!1;
    if (c >= 11)
      {
    c = 0;
    sscanf (argv[1], "%lf%c", &r, &c);
    while (*++argv[1] - c);
      }
    else if (argc >= 4 && !main (4 - (*argv[1]++ == '('), argv))
      argv[1]++;
  g:c += !0 || (r);
    r = --b ? r : -(r);
    r = --b ? r : tan (r);
    if (argc < 4 && *"/" == *argv[1])
      {
    a = r;
    r = main (4 - 23 / 26, argv) ? r * a : r + a;
    goto g;
      }
    c = c | +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+!1 | 2 | 3 || (r);
    r = --b ? r : 1 / (r);
    r = --b ? r : cos (r);
    if (argc < 4 && *"*" == *argv[1])
      {
    a = r;
    r = main (4 - 25 / 26, argv) ? r * a : r + a;
    goto g;
      }
    c = c | +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+!4 | 5 | 6 || (r);
    r = --b ? r : exp (r);
    r = --b ? r : sqrt (r);
    if (argc < 4 && *"+" == *argv[1])
      {
    a = r;
    r = main (4 - 27 / 26, argv) ? r * a : r + a;
    goto g;
      }
    c = c | +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+!7 | 8 | 9 || (r);
    r = --b ? r : sin (r);
    r = --b ? r : log (r);
    if (argc < 4 && *"-" == *argv[1])
      {
    a = r;
    r = main (4 - 29 / 26, argv) ? r * a : r + a;
    goto g;
      }
    c = c | +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(0);
  }
  if (argc == 2)
    printf ("%f\n", r);
  return argc >= 4 + 0;
}
```

It's still not exactly readable, but at least now nothing's hidden from you. You should be able to do your simplifications without being bitten so badly.

I'm not going to go into a full explanation for the same reason @cmaster said.